# Horizontal Border Gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

This may seem trivial but I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere. I'm trying to make a border change to a gradient fill on hover.

Here's the codepen; https://codepen.io/gavdraws/pen/LyWJML

As you'll see, the vertical borders on each side work as intended, the horizontal ones do not.

EDIT: I've cleared the codepen clutter and created a fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/6dwx4eos/

All help appreciated.

For clarification:

```
/* Working */
.frame.leftFrame {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-left: 45px solid #EDEDED;
  border-top: 45px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.frame.leftFrame:hover{
  border-left: 45px solid #F1612F;
  -webkit-border-image: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #f26739, #f68a22); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  -webkit-border-image: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #f26739, #f68a22) 1 100%;
  -moz-border-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #f26739, #f68a22) 1 100%;  
  -o-border-image:
    -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #f26739, #f68a22) 1 100%;
  border-image:
     linear-gradient(to bottom, #f26739, #f68a22) 1 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Not Working */
.frame.topFrame {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border-top: 45px solid #EDEDED;
  border-left: 45px solid transparent;
  border-right: 45px solid transparent;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.frame.topFrame:hover{
  border-top: 45px solid #F1612F;
  content: "";
  -webkit-border-image: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #f26739, #f68a22); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  -webkit-border-image: 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #f26739, #f68a22) 1 100%;
  -moz-border-image:
    -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #f26739, #f68a22) 1 100%;  
  -o-border-image:
    -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #f26739, #f68a22) 1 100%;
  border-image:
  linear-gradient(to bottom, #f26739, #f68a22) 1 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.frame.topFrame:hover` change the gradient from `bottom` to `left` or `right` so that the gradient has room to render. The gradient applies to the total width or height of the container, but only had 45 pixels to show gradation, meaning it was there but only slightly.

Comment: Hi Karson. Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately I still see the same bug in Chrome and Safari